# Python: how to avoid code duplication in exception catching?

Tags: python, exception

What is a good pattern to avoid code duplication when dealing with different exception types in Python, eg. I want to treat URLError and HTTPError simlar but not quite:

```
try:
    page = urlopen(request)
except URLError, err:
    logger.error("An error ocurred %s", err)
except HTTPError, err:
    logger.error("An error occured %s", err)
    logger.error("Error message: %s", err.read())
```

In this example, I would like to avoid the duplication of the first logger.error call. Given URLError is the parent of HTTPError one could do something like this:

```
except URLError, err:
    logger.error("An error occurred %s", err)
    try:
         raise err
    except HTTPError, err:
         # specialization for http errors
         logger.error("Error message: %s", err.read())
    except:
        pass
```

Another approach would be to use isinstance eg. if URLError and HTTPError would not be in a chain of inheritance:

```
except (URLError, HTTPError), err:
    logger.error("An error occured %s", err)
    if isinstance(err, HTTPError):
         logger.error("Error message: %s", err.read())
```

Which one should I prefer, is there another better approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that your third example is the best solution.

- It's the shortest version
- It avoids duplication
- It is clear to read and easy to follow, much unlike the second version.

You might want to use the newer `except FooError as err` syntax, though, if you're on Python 2.6 or higher.

Also, in your example, the first version isn't quite correct since the `URLError` handler already catches the `HTTPError`, so the `except HTTPError` part is never reached. You'd have to switch the two `except`s around. Another reason not to use this.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That's convincing. Great you spotted the URLError, HTTPError ordering in the first example. I don't edit the question as it clearly indicates the problem with that example as you mentioned in your answer.